# how to store contact in local database in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contacts

I am building an android application where I need to read all the contact of the user phone and store in my sqLite. The problem is how to get the contact and in case if there are 3 number with one name then how to store 3 number with that particular name please help me or give me some point step. to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) 
{
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) 
    {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {
            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
            ContentResolver contentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
            boolean hasPhoneNumberFlag = false;

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) 
            {
                Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=" + Integer.valueOf(contact_id), null, null);

                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);
                int count = 0;
                if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.getCount() != 0) 
                {
                    int c = phoneCursor.getCount();
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    }

                }
                if (phoneCursor != null) 
                {
                    phoneCursor.close();
                } 

                // insert in database
                ContentValues valuesFor_Contact = new ContentValues();
                valuesFor_Contact.put("phonenumber", phone);
                myDataBase.insert(TableName_Contacts, null, valuesFor_Contact);
            }

        }

    }

    if (cursor != null) 
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```